# How to handle negative edge weights in distance vector routing protocol with a digraph?

Tags: graphs, shortest-path, weighted-graphs

In a Distance Vector routing protocol each node implements a Bellman-Ford inspired algorithm that shares it's routing table (Distance Vector) with each of it's incoming links (upstream neighbors).  How would a source node identify a destination node it could reach at an infinitely low cost by traversing a negative cycle over and over again?

Comment: The Bellman-Ford algorithm [is able to detect negative cycles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm#Finding_negative_cycles) and hence can "interrupt" there, it does not loop forever. However the problem of minimum paths cannot be solved in presence of negative cycles, so if you find one you somehow have to remove it from the graph.

Comment: I do understand that but since this is for distance vector routing the implementation of every router is the same but it has to be implemented in a way where you only initially know about yourself and your directly connected neighbors.  It is not truly Bellman-Ford